# How can I delay a php functions for days?

Tags: php, background, wait, sleep, timing

Function, which waits about one day in the background and then execute another.

Like:

```
function Sleep(){
    sleep( /* One Day */ );
    Run();
}
function Run(){
    //One Day later,
    //execute code.
}
```

Or maby something like this (this is fictional):

```
class Waiter extends Timer{
    $time = 0;
    function __construct($time){
        $this->time = $time;
    }
    function onDelay(){
        //One day Later.
    }
}
$wait = new Waiter( /* One Day */ );
```

Is there a good solution?

Or is the sleep() function also okey?
But I have to say, that the execution timeout is 30 seconds.

Comment: Why don't you use cron job?

Comment: What's the context ? Web page ? service written with PHP CLI ?

Comment: Cron would be optimum in most cases.

Comment: @Mr.Engineer Or, for one-time calls, `at`.

Comment: Put the job on a queue system like RabbitMQ or Gearman with a time limit before it should be consumed?

Comment: without Cron job it is not possible

Comment: As @MarkBaker mentioned, using a queue system.  You could go old school and make a simple DB table that has a run date, and then triggers the proper method.  This would also require cron.

Answer (score 1):

Using a **cronjob** is the correct solution for this problem. If for some reason you cannot use it, make sure to add  `ignore_user_abort(1)`  and `set_time_limit(0);` at the top of the php script.

---

```
int ignore_user_abort ([ bool $value ] )
```

> When running PHP as a command line script, and the script's tty goes
> away without the script being terminated then the script will die the
> next time it tries to write anything, unless value is set to TRUE

```
bool set_time_limit ( int $seconds )
```

> Set the number of seconds a script is allowed to run. If this is
> reached, the script returns a fatal error. The default limit is 30
> seconds or, if it exists, the max_execution_time value defined in the
> php.ini.
>
> When called, set_time_limit() restarts the timeout counter from zero.
> In other words, if the timeout is the default 30 seconds, and 25
> seconds into script execution a call such as set_time_limit(20) is
> made, the script will run for a total of 45 seconds before timing out.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, the execution time is 30 seconds, the overall script is forced to an end after 30 seconds. It can't wait longer.

As already suggested, you could use a cron job.

If your problem is not regular recurrent, you could write a little script, which writes the time (with date) when the function should execute into a file (or a database). The cron then would execute every hour (or if its important, every minute) and checks, if the function needs to be executed

Answer (score 0):

Crons have been mentioned, but there's a second option - queueing.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue

There is a wide variety of queue software available, from ones you install yourself like Beanstalk or RabbitMQ to hosted ones in the cloud like Amazon SQS or IronMQ.